# c++ win32 SendInput()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

How can I simulate key press with SendInput()?

I want to make it to simulate for example in a notepad to press shift+q. So a Q would appear in the notepad if I run my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 4 inputs: shift down, q down, q up, shift up. Therefore, use a `INPUT[4]`.

Comment: Fails when the Ctrl or Alt key is down.

Comment: Depends on interpretation. You simulate Ctrl-Shift-Q when Ctrl is already down. But when Ctrl is down, pressing shift-q _does_ produce Ctrl-shift-q, so the simulation is accurate. (A similar issue exists with Caps Lock. Do you really intend to send shift-q or did you actually mean uppercase Q?)

Comment: Thanks, this the answer for me question but unfortunately it doesn't work the way I wanted it. I wanted it to work in a game to simulate shift+q in this way it should cast a spell but nothing. I set it to T to "cast", so if I press T it write a Q into a notepad but in the game nothing... :/
Any idea?

Comment: @Gaboros: you really should have mentioned that; games may be using DirectInput.

Comment: I didn't thought about this method will won't work. Sorry I'm beginner who just learning :/
Anyway strange because this method can write into the games chat but doesn't simulate casting a spell. I try to learn about that DirectInput You mentioned, thank You!